# Download file from URL using flutter web

Tags: flutter, download, flutter-web

right now i am trying to add a feature where the user can download the files uploaded by them through the URL,
I have tried this code sample:

```
html.AnchorElement anchorElement =  new html.AnchorElement(href: "https://www.example.com/file/path/");
   anchorElement.download = "https://www.example.com/file/path/";
   anchorElement.click();
```

But it simply opens the file on the browser, which is not what i want, anyone got any other suggestions?